# want to share app only by email in iOS using UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

So basically I want to share the content only through mail and I do not want to show the option of message. Could you help me out with that. Also I want to set the subject of the email through the code and also the recipient of the email through the code

Comment: Why do you need `UIActivityViewController` if you can use `MFMailComposeViewController `?

Comment: You can set itunes url as sharing string . Based on Activity type selected you can define subject (like for email )

Answer (score 1):

You can put this in the method for a button tap or something like that.

```
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
            MFMailComposeViewController *mailViewController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
            mailViewController.mailComposeDelegate = controller;
            [mailViewController setSubject:subject];
            NSMutableArray *emails = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            [emails addObject:address];
            [mailViewController setToRecipients:emails];
            mailViewController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
            mailViewController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            mailViewController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]};
            [controller presentViewController:mailViewController animated:YES completion:^{
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent animated:NO];
            }];
        }
```

Comment: thanks  ... it is good to use rather then UIActivityViewController